# How to use string to find object key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

How can I select an object key in a theme object using a string used in react component prop?

theme

```
{
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#dc2626',
      dark: '#7f1d1d',
      light: '#fecaca',
    }
    text: '#111827',
  }
}
```

component

```
const Typography = ({ color, children }) => (
  <p style={{ color: theme.palette[color] }}>{children}</p>
);
```

How I want to use the component:

```
<Typography color='primary.main'>Hello world</Typography>
```

Let me know if this is a bad practice and should be avoided anyway.

I tried to use the eval function but found out it was not secure and considered to be a bad practice.

Comment: How about having 2 props, one for parent and one for the color? And also have a default value if either of the props are not passed.

Comment: I want it to be flexible and also use it if theme has more deeply nested styles in the future.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking how to get a nested field in an object, you should look at lodash's [get function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get).

#### Example :

```
export default const theme = {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#dc2626',
      dark: '#7f1d1d',
      light: '#fecaca',
    }
    text: '#111827',
  }
};
```

Component

```
import { get } from lodash library;
import theme from './theme.js';

export default function MyComponent({ children }) {
  const nestedFieldPath = 'palette.primary.main';

  // Get nested field value
  const nestedFieldValue = get(theme, nestedFieldPath);

  return <p color={nestedFieldValue}>{children}</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution, **without using any additional libraries**.

Idea is to create a function with method for getting the nested color value from your Theme object and then use that function (getColor) in your components.

**This can handle additional levels of nesting.**

Bare in mind, my experience with React is reading 3 pages of docs.
It is not clear from question how you want to handle situation when you try to get color that is not in theme, you would have to handle that inside reduce.

```
function Theme () {
  let palette = {
        primary: {
          main: '#dc2626',
          dark: '#7f1d1d',
          light: '#fecaca',
        },
        secondary : {
          green: {
              lightgreen : 'myfancycolor :)'
            } 
        }
      }
  this.getColor = function(string){
    let nesting = string.split(".");
    const result = nesting.reduce(
      (accumulator, currentValue) => {
            if (accumulator[currentValue])
                return accumulator[currentValue];
            else
                return accumulator
        } ,
      palette
    );
    return result;
  }
}

let myTheme = new Theme();
console.log(myTheme.getColor("secondary.green.lightgreen"))
//prints myfancycolor :)
```

Usage in component:

```
const Typography = ({ color, children }) => (
  <p style={{ color: myTheme.getColor("primary.dark") }}>{children}</p>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a hook that can be extended as well as handle a default incase no color is being passed to your typography component

Example hook:

```
import React from "react";

const useColor = (color = null) => {
  // Set the default theme
  const [selectedTheme, setSelectedTheme] = React.useState(["primary", "main"]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (color) {
      setSelectedTheme(color.split("."));
    }
  }, [color]);

  return selectedTheme;
};
export default useColor;
```

Then the Typography component you're returning an array from the hook so deconstruct it into 2 values. Naming is of course questionable here :

```
const Typography = ({ color, children }) => {
  const [level, choice] = useColor(color);
  return <p style={{ color: theme.palette[level][choice] }}>{children}</p>;
};
```

Usage:

```
<Typography color={"primary.main"}>Hello</Typography>
```

A codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-julien-rr0tuf?file=/src/App.js:506-561